# Can Google+ API make posts?

Tags: google-plus

Google+ API provides read-only access to public data for long time. Can Google+ developers inform us whether they are going to give access to make posts using API? I need to post some images with text from my website using API. I have been waiting for this for long time please.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it used google + domain api https://developers.google.com/+/domains/ .
But you must have domain.

You can use https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client this help you post.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is different in Google+ domains? Having a domain is not an issue. Is this the only requirement?

Comment: If you have domain you can post on google + profile, but unfortunately your post can see only user under your domain. Why? I searching answer on this question now, I let you know when find something.

Comment: You mean only my friends can see the post? Or what do you mean by "user under your domain"

Comment: If you have domain you must create organization and when you post by domain+ api, post will be available only for your organization people. Now I try find something what would resolve this issue but until I found nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, I have been trying to find the solution for a long time... because I need to make public posts into my profile and many people are looking forward for this feature in Google API. If you can find something please let us know.

Comment: Yes sure. I let you know necessarily.

Comment: I have bad news, I spoke with support and google developer, but what we have at today we can just post on google plus with restricted for domain(organization). But if it help you after post you can repost by handle and give public type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you clarify what you mean by "can repost by handle and give public type" I did not get what this means. Does this mean there is a way to make my post public?

Comment: By api: no, 
but if you want post manually on google + : yes
When you post by api your post will be restricted for your organization.
And you can look at on this post in your google+ account, on there have option re post  and you can re post your post and make permission with public.

Comment: I see... so there is still no such functionality. Several years passed, I guess, since I started looking for this feature. All social networks allow this by API using OAuth. I don't know why Google is keeping itself out of this.

Comment: I don't know too, I hope that someday they will change it.

Answer (score 0):

Google generally doesn't comment on potential future updates.